# i keep getting into this error while running this java code

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, calculation

Im trying to make a calculator program which can do addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, but i keep getting this error after the main method is executed

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at Java_Calculator.calculation(Java_Calculator.java:36)
        at Java_Calculator.main(Java_Calculator.java:19)
        at Java_Calculator.main(Java_Calculator.java:5)
```

Here is my code for reference.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java_Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main();
        
    }
    static void main(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to Java Calculator!!");
        System.out.println("By-theclassicalguy");
        System.out.println("<------------------------------------------------------>");
        System.out.println("1. Perform a Calculation");
        System.out.println("2. Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice (1/2):");
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int user_choice=input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        if (user_choice==1){
            calculation();

        }else{
            System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");

        }

    }

    static void calculation(){
        System.out.println("1. Add");
        System.out.println("2. Subtract");
        System.out.println("3. Multiply");
        System.out.println("4. Divide");
        Scanner calc_choice=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your choice (1/2/3/4):");
        
        int choice=calc_choice.nextInt();
        calc_choice.close();
        if (choice==1){
            add();
        } else if(choice==2){
            sub();

        }else if(choice==3){
            mult();
            
        }else if(choice==4){
            div();
            
        }


    }

    static void add(){
        Scanner num1= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        double a=num1.nextDouble();
        num1.close();
        Scanner num2= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a second number");
        double b=num2.nextDouble();
        num2.close();
        double add=a+b;
        System.out.println("The sum is "+add);
        
    }

    static void sub(){
        Scanner num1= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        double a=num1.nextDouble();
        num1.close();
        Scanner num2= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a seconf number:");
        double b=num2.nextDouble();
        num2.close();
        double sub=a-b;
        System.out.println("The difference is "+sub);
    }
    static void mult(){
        Scanner num1= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        double a=num1.nextDouble();
        num1.close();
        Scanner num2= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a second number:");
        double b=num2.nextDouble();
        num2.close();
        double mult=a*b;
        System.out.println("The sum is "+mult);
    }
    static void div(){
        Scanner num1= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numerator:");
        double a=num1.nextDouble();
        num1.close();
        Scanner num2= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a denominator");
        double b=num2.nextDouble();
        num2.close();
        double div=a/b;
        System.out.println("The sum is "+div);
    }

    



}
```

Basically, what i wanted to do was to create multiple methods each with its particular function like addition, subtraction etc. and these functions will be linked to another calculations method which is again linked to another method called main. in each method ive added a scanner class to collect the numbers from the user. but i keep getting the error mention above,when i run the program, the main method runs properly then when i type 1 to proceed to the calculations method, which also prints what is required but after that  instead of the scanner class working and asking me to answer, it prints the error and exits from the program.

Comment: `num1.close();` will close `System.in`. After that, you cannot read from it any more, which causes that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are experiencing is due to the way you are using the Scanner object and subsequently closing it. When you close the Scanner object that is attached to `System.in`, you are essentially closing the underlying input stream (`System.in`). Once you close that stream, you can't read from it again using another Scanner or any other method.

To fix this, you should use a single Scanner object for all your input, and avoid closing it until your program is completely done with user input.

I created an example using an online Java compiler, test it here:
http://tpcg.io/_WXXH4N

Revised code with a working scanner:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java_Calculator {
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Single scanner object for the entire program

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainMenu();
    }

    static void mainMenu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Java Calculator!!");
        System.out.println("By-theclassicalguy");
        System.out.println("<------------------------------------------------------>");
        System.out.println("1. Perform a Calculation");
        System.out.println("2. Exit");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice (1/2): ");

        int user_choice = scanner.nextInt();
        if (user_choice == 1) {
            calculation();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");
        }
    }

    static void calculation() {
        System.out.println("1. Add");
        System.out.println("2. Subtract");
        System.out.println("3. Multiply");
        System.out.println("4. Divide");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice (1/2/3/4): ");

        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                add();
                break;
            case 2:
                sub();
                break;
            case 3:
                mult();
                break;
            case 4:
                div();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
    }

    static double readNumber(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    static void add() {
        double a = readNumber("Enter a number: ");
        double b = readNumber("Enter a second number: ");
        System.out.println("The sum is " + (a + b));
    }

    static void sub() {
        double a = readNumber("Enter a number: ");
        double b = readNumber("Enter a second number: ");
        System.out.println("The difference is " + (a - b));
    }

    static void mult() {
        double a = readNumber("Enter a number: ");
        double b = readNumber("Enter a second number: ");
        System.out.println("The product is " + (a * b));
    }

    static void div() {
        double a = readNumber("Enter numerator: ");
        double b;
        do {
            b = readNumber("Enter a denominator: ");
            if (b == 0) {
                System.out.println("Denominator cannot be zero. Please enter again.");
            }
        } while (b == 0);
        System.out.println("The result is " + (a / b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm from a python background and am really new to java. i was not able to understand this part,  `static double readNumber(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }` and this part `private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`, and also where have you closed the Scanner?